# Which Version of TurboGears should I use for a new project?

Tags: python, project, turbogears

I'm planing a new project and I want to use [TurboGears](http://www.turbogears.org). The problem is: I'm not sure which version to choose. There are three choices:
Turbogears 1.0.8 (stable)
Turbogears 1.1 (beta 3)
Turbogears 2.0 (beta 4)

As this is a new project I dont want to choose the wrong framework. So where are the differeneces, how "beta" is 2.0?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally would go with TG2 (but would also look at other frameworks such as Pylons or repoze.bfg) esp. if it's a new project. Remember that you might need to upgrade at some point (or want to at least). TG2 also is offers full WSGI support which gains more and more traction and is IMHO also something you really want.

For me the most important thing these days is always how good the code of that framework looks like because you never know when you need to dig into it to try to understand some misbehaviour or even fix a bug (regardless of what version).

Another important aspect is IMHO the community, so hanging around in IRC channels or on mailing lists for a bit might help you to make better decision.

Maybe [these 10 reasons to use TG2](http://compoundthinking.com/blog/index.php/2008/07/31/10-reasons-why-the-new-turbogears-2-alpha-is-worth-a-look/) also help.

Comment: TG2 gets my vote too - it's been in beta for some time now and a final release is definitely within sight. The community is great, and the heavy TG presence at PyCon will only help that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TG2.  TG1.0.x is legacy, and TG1.1 is meant as a stepping stone to TG2 for legacy apps.

I'd look very seriously at Pylons and Django too.